# How to run script from django?

Tags: python, django, shell

I would like to know how to run a script from a django view.

It works from the command line: Eg: `$ python sync.py` But not via the django view. Thanks in advance

## script 1: /home/ubuntu/webapps/sony_mv/sync.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import call
call(["/bin/sh", "/home/ubuntu/webapps/sony_mv/sync.sh"])
```

## script 2: /home/ubuntu/webapps/sony_mv/sync.sh

```
cd /home/ubuntu/webapps/sony_mv
heroku pgbackups:capture -a staging-db --expire
heroku pgbackups:capture -a prod-db --expire
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE -a prod-db `heroku pgbackups:url -a staging-d` --confirm prod-db
```

## views.py

```
def sync_staging_to_production(request):
    try:
        token = request.GET['token']
    except:
        token = False
    if token == '382749813256-231952135':
        from subprocess import *
        import sys
        p = Popen([sys.executable, '/home/ubuntu/webapps/sony_mv/sync.py'],stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT)
        return render_to_response('hannibal/sync_staging_to_production.html',{'feedback':'Success. Sync in progress.'},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('hannibal/sync_staging_to_production.html',{'feedback':'Authorization required'},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## ls output

```
 $ ls -l sync.*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root 108 2013-04-09 16:35 sync.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root 326 2013-04-09 16:44 sync.sh
```

## whoami output

```
$ python
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call(["/usr/bin/whoami"])
ubuntu
0
>>>
```

Comment: If you were to `call(["/bin/sh", "whoami"])`, what would the result be? What is the ownership of sync.sh?

Comment: whoami returns ubuntu. Script ownership is root. Please refer to the updates in the post for details.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" from the Django view?  What were you expecting?

Comment: No, my intent was to find out what user is running django. The way you ran it, you're running it as yourself. With your webserver running, do `ps -ef | grep django` and see what user is really running it.

Comment: @Joe Frambach - Django is running via the user 'www-data'

Comment: @Austin Phillips - The script can be executed successfully from the terminal, but it does not work via django in views.py

Comment: I don't think heroku copies file permissions. My best guess is that it's uploading your files with a temporary user's ownership, and running django as www-data. Just a hunch though.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will update my shell scripts to log the output and verify permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a log for the output of the shell commands helped to debug.
The issue was related with permissions and ssh keys for the corresponding user.
Adding the corresponding user SSH keys fixed the issue.

Thanks everyone